# dbms_output.put is not printing data

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a simple program in plsql. Basically the program has no errors but is not printing output when I use dbms_output.put.

```
declare
v_name varchar(30);
v_len number;
v_number number;
  begin
    v_name := '&name';
    v_number := length(v_name);
    while v_number > 0
    loop
      dbms_output.put(v_number||'::'||substr(v_name,v_number,1));
      v_number := v_number - 1;
    end loop;
  end;
```

The above program produces output when I use dbms_output.put_line but the output has new line after ever character and I would like to have the output in a single horizontal line. On using dbms_output.put it doesn't throw any error but it just gives me the message:
"anonymous block completed"

Please let me know if am doing anything wrong.

Thanks,
Dex.

Comment: Thank You guys. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: Just add dbms_output.put_line('') or dbms_output.new_line at the end of the loop.

```
declare
v_name varchar(30);
v_len number;
v_number number;
  BEGIN

    v_name := :name;
    v_number := length(v_name);
    while v_number > 0
    loop
      dbms_output.put(v_number||'::'||substr(v_name,v_number,1)|| ' ' );
      v_number := v_number - 1;
    END loop;

    dbms_output.new_line;
  end;
```

P.S. Please refrain from using '&' for substitution variable (`&name`) in pl/sql since its a feature supported by SQL*Plus. Instead, use bind variable like this `:name`

Comment: This will work, but isn't it better to just build a VARCHAR2 string in the loop, and place the whole string in the output buffer all at once, with a PUT_LINE call?

Comment: thats a good suggestion and a better answer. But In my view, Im just giving him the fix for his code. If he had asked for a better solution or a suggestion, your answer should have been accepted if you have posted it. just saying. =)

Answer (score 1):

`DBMS_OUTPUT` does not appear to flush the buffer until a new line is sent; you can either use `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( NULL )` or `DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE` like this:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
declare
v_name varchar(30);
v_len number;
v_number number;
begin
  v_name := '&name';
  v_number := length(v_name);
  while v_number > 0
  loop
    dbms_output.put(v_number||'::'||substr(v_name,v_number,1));
    v_number := v_number - 1;
  end loop;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE;
end;
/
```